# Hide menu item based on user's custom capability

Tags: menus, user-meta, capabilities

I need to show one item from menu only for users that are logged in and have certain custom capability set.

Is it doable from theme functions.php or does it need a custom plugin?

Note: I already use a plugin to show/hide menu items based on user roles, but couldn't find anything for Custom Capabilities (user meta value).

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin provides filter to manage the menu item by meta value:

```
function custom_menu_item_visibility( $visible, $item ){ 
    if( isset( $item->roles ) ){ 
        $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
        $user_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'your-meta-key', true ); 
        if ( /* your condition */ ){ 
            $visible = true; 
        } else { 
            $visible = false; 
        } 
    } 
    return $visible; 
} 
add_filter( 'nav_menu_roles_item_visibility', 'custom_menu_item_visibility', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable menu item based on user role you can try this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/

Comment: as i wrote in note i already have plugin to display item based on role. I need to display/hide item based on custom capability (user meta value)

Comment: This plugin provides filter to manage the menu item by meta value:
function custom_menu_item_visibility( $visible, $item ){

    if( isset( $item->roles ) ){
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $user_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'your-meta-key', true );
        if ( /* your condition */ ){
            $visible = true;
        } else {
            $visible = false;
        }
    }
return $visible;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_roles_item_visibility', 'custom_menu_item_visibility', 10, 2 );

Comment: would you mind editing answer and pasting code there for easier readability?